# Getting rid of the `if` statements when creating dynamic subtypes

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Its a question mainly about design.

Lets suppose we have a class that has the role of initiating different subclasses of a certain type by some parameters that it is iterating through. The problem comes when the `__init__` method receives different parameter for each subtype. Is there any way to avoid the `if` statements inside the function that initializes the classes just to know what parameters to pass in? Maybe some design pattern that I am not aware of. Or is it an outcome of a bad design?

below is an example of what I mean. notice the manage static method that has the if...else... in it and if there were more types of workers, we would have more if's, which is what I am trying to avoid.
Keep in mind that the example is minimal, and the `if` statements can be much more complex.

```
from abc import ABCMeta


class BaseWorker(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def work(self):
        pass


class Worker1(BaseWorker):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def work(self):
        pass


class Worker2(BaseWorker):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def work(self):
        pass


class Manager(object):
    @staticmethod
    def manage(attributes_list):
        for attributes in attributes_list:
            if "age" in attributes:
                w = Worker2(name=attributes["name"], age=attributes["age"])
            else:
                w = Worker1(name=attributes["name"])
            w.work()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dynamic_attributes = [
        {"name": "davay"},
        {"age": "55", "name": "ok"},
        # and so on...
    ]
    Manager.manage(dynamic_attributes)
```

And the desired solution would have been

```
    @staticmethod
    def desired_manage(attributes_list):
        for attributes in attributes_list:
            w = worker_factory(attributes)
            w.work()
```

**** Notice that the `worker_factory` is just an arbitrary name for the way that will solve this issue, it doesn't mean that factory pattern is the way to go.
Even less, if we try factory pattern, from what I can see, the `if` statements will just move there and it wont solve anything.**

Thanks!

Comment: You could put map attributes to their corresponding classes in a dict and do something like `klass_ = mapping.get(attr, default_class)`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @snakecharmerb its a possible idea, but what if the `if` statements were more complex? I am looking for something more robust.

Comment: If the conditions are more complex I'd probably use an if/elif chain, though maybe you could do something with tuples as keys.  I don't really understand why you don't want to use ifs: if the code has to branch, it has to branch and a factory function/method is a good place to isolate the branching code.

Comment: @snakecharmerb the reason why I dont like the chain if `if` statements is that every time I'll want to add a new class (new worker in this case) i will have to make the chain larger, which means there will be chages to an existing code.
I don't want to change existing code, it violates SOLID principles and it is error prone.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to register each subclass with the Manager, along with a callable that determines whether the subclass should be instantiated.

Something like this (untested):

```
class Manager(object):

    _registry = []
    _default = None

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, callable, klass):
        cls._registry.append((callable, klass))
        return

    @classmethod
    def register_default(cls, klass):
        cls._default = klass
        return

    @staticmethod
    def manage(attributes_list):
        for attributes in attributes_list:
            for callable, klass in Manager._registry:
                if callable(attributes):
                    w = klass(**attributes)
                    break
        else:
            w = Manager._default(**attrs)
        w.work()


class BaseWorker(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def work(self):
        pass


class Worker1(BaseWorker):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

Manager.register_default(Worker1)  


class Worker2(BaseWorker):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age 

Manager.register(Worker2, lambda attrs: 'age' in attrs)
```

This method has some drawbacks:

- Conditions are tested in insertion order, so you need to ensure that stricter conditions for example `'name' in attrs and 'age' in attrs` are tested before laxer conditions like `'name' in attrs`.  This may be challenging if subclasses are defined in different modules.  Perhaps add a priority to each `(callable, klass)` tuple that can be used to sort the registry
- The nested loop may be slow if `attributes_list` is large (and/or there are a lot of subclasses)

Answer (score 0):

if subclasses will share work method in the end, then you do not need this subclasses and implementing them will be bad design, adding unnecessarily difficulties. you could just use default values in **init** for not required parameters, and then it can receives different parameter for each subtype without complaining.

```
from abc import ABCMeta


class BaseWorker(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def work(self):
        pass


class Worker(BaseWorker):
    def __init__(self, name, age=None, address=None, sex=None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        address= address
        sex= sex

    def work(self):
        pass


class Manager(object):
    @staticmethod
    def manage(attributes_list):
        for attributes in attributes_list:
            w = Worker(**attributes)
            w.work()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dynamic_attributes = [
        {"name": "davay"},
        {"name": "aa", "age": "55"},
        {"name": "bb", "sex": "female"},
        {"name": "cc", "address": "123 street", "age": "43"},
        # and so on...
    ]
    Manager.manage(dynamic_attributes)
```

Comment: This is considering that the json is in a certain order. It might not be the case.
Classes will not share the same work, the implementation will be different.

Comment: hi @max , no need to be in certain order. and this is not json, looks like one but it's a python list of dictionaries.

Comment: you're right, but still it wont matter because the different workers will have different implementation of the method `work`.

Comment: so say, if you init a worker with name , this will have different work than worker init with name, and age ? this will be a buggy design, imo. sorry i wasn't able to help.